# Entities aren't passed in many-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core, aspnetboilerplate

I have created a many-to-many relation `EventUser` which holds the `userId`, `EventId` and the `User` and `Event` objects, aswell as an `isPresent` boolean which I use to manage the presence for the User for that Event.

I create the `EventUser` by setting both the Id's and objects, and then adding it to the `Event's` `EventUser` List. When I get the `Events` from the database however, the list of `EventUsers` only returns data the `UserId`, `EventId` and the `IsPresent` fields, the `User` and `Event` fields return `null`.

These are my classes:

User entity

```
public class User : AbpUser<User>
    {
        public const string DefaultPassword = "123qwe";
        public string Instrument { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<EventUser> EventUsers { get; set; }

        public static string CreateRandomPassword()
        {
            return Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N").Truncate(16);
        }

        public static User CreateTenantAdminUser(int tenantId, string emailAddress)
        {
            var user = new User
            {
                TenantId = tenantId,
                UserName = AdminUserName,
                Name = AdminUserName,
                Surname = AdminUserName,
                EmailAddress = emailAddress,
                Roles = new List<UserRole>(),
            };

            user.SetNormalizedNames();

            return user;
        }
    }
```

Event entity

```
    public class Event : Entity
    {
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }

        public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }

        public bool IsConfirmed { get; set; }

        public int GroupId { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<EventUser> EventUsers { get; set; }

        public Event()
        {
            EventUsers = new List<EventUser>();
        }
    }
```

EventUser class

```
    public class EventUser : Entity
    {
        public int EventId { get; set; }
        public Event Event { get; set; }
        public long UserId { get; set; }
        public User User { get; set; }

        public bool IsPresent { get; set; }
    }
```

OnModelCreating method in my DbContext in which i create the many-to-many relationship

```
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<EventUser>().HasKey(eu => new { eu.EventId, eu.UserId }); //.isUnique()?
            modelBuilder.Entity<EventUser>().HasOne(eu => eu.Event)
                .WithMany(e => e.EventUsers)
                .HasForeignKey(eu => eu.EventId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<EventUser>().HasOne(eu => eu.User)
                .WithMany(u => u.EventUsers)
                .HasForeignKey(eu => eu.UserId);
        }
```

AddGroupUsersToEvent method in the EventAppService in which I create and add all the users of a group to the event as EventUsers.

```
        public void AddAllEventUsersFromGroup(AddAllEventUsersFromGroupDto dto)
        {
            var e = _eventManager.GetEventById(dto.EventId);
            var g = _groupManager.QueryGroups().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == dto.GroupId);

            foreach (var user in g.Users)
            {
                var eu = new EventUser
                {
                    EventId = e.Id,
                    Event = e,
                    UserId = user.Id,
                    User = user
                };
                e.EventUsers.Add(eu);
            }
            _eventManager.Update(e);
        }
```

ListAll method in the EventAppService in which I list all the events

```
        public IEnumerable<EventDto> ListAll()
        {
            var result = _eventManager.QueryEvents().Select(e => new EventDto
            {
                Id = e.Id,
                Name = e.Name,
                Location = e.Location,
                Address = e.Address,
                StartTime = e.StartTime,
                EndTime = e.EndTime,
                GroupId = e.GroupId,
                EventUsers = e.EventUsers
            }).OrderBy(e => e.StartTime).ToList();
            return result;
        }
```

If I run the ListAll method in Swagger it returns the EventUsers list from an event like this:

```
      "eventUsers": [
        {
          "eventId": 3,
          "event": null,
          "userId": 4,
          "user": null,
          "isPresent": true,
          "id": 0
        }
    ]
```

Do I have to include the event and user object somewhere when getting the Events? While debugging I found out that the Event and User objects are fine when I use them to create the EventUser, but are returned as `null` once I get the event.

Comment: Try `EventUsers = e.EventUsers.Select(eu => new EventUser { Event = eu.Event, User = eu.User })`.

Comment: Thank you @aaron! This fixed my problem! Because the eventUsers is a list I still had to call the `ToList()` method at the end of this statement but it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aaron's answer worked for me! The only thing i had to do, was to call the `ToList()` method after the statement because it expects an ICollection and not an IEnumerable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly load related data while you getting them from repository,

```
Repository.GetAll()
                .Include(x => x.Event)
                .Include(x => x.User)
```